# Create a toolbar button to change sort order of emails in Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a friend who is virtually blind. He wants his emails to be sorted by descending order of received date. He keeps clicking on other field names by accident and then cannot find how to sort by received date again. He has screen reading software but it does not appear to read the column headers.

I want to create a button on the toolbar that would sort the emails by received date, either by calling a macro or any other means.  The screen reading software would help him find the button - but it seems surprisingly difficult to get this button to work as needed.

I've tried using `Items.sort`, but this does not seem to affect the display view.

I tried setting up a new view called "Inbox sorted" so I could switch to this view using VBA, but the problem with the named view is when I click on another column to sort, e.g. "size", this seems to permanently change the view so it's now sorted by size whenever recalled - so when my macro calls up this view it's sorted by size instead of by date as needed. There is a reset button on the toolbar, but it's greyed out.

I found there is some XML associated with the view. I can read it using:

```
Debug.Print Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.CurrentView.XML
```

but I have no idea how to safely edit this.

Any thoughts? It doesn't have to be done by a macro; all I want is to make it easier for him to have his inbox sorted by date, and I'm open to any way of achieving this.

Edit: the code I wrote to change view is:

```
Sub ChangeViewToInboxSorted()

Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
myOlExp.CurrentView = "Inbox Sorted"

End Sub
```

This doesn't do the job because as I mentioned, clicking on a column heading at any time the view is active permanently changes the definition of the view.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

The `Items.Sort` and the View are different things. The Sort methods do the job only in the memory, not the UI.

To get the desired XML markup of sorted items I'd recommend doing the required changes manually in Outlook and then checking the result using the XML property in the code. Thus, you will find out how it should like.